# how does one import and use the xtermjs fitAddon?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, xtermjs

I'm trying to follow the docs for xterm.js and the "FitAddon" has this example.

```
import { Terminal } from 'xterm';
import { FitAddon } from 'xterm-addon-fit';

const term = new Terminal();
const fitAddon = new FitAddon();
term.loadAddon(fitAddon);

// Open the terminal in #terminal-container
term.open(document.getElementById('terminal-container'));

// Make the terminal's size and geometry fit the size of #terminal-container
fitAddon.fit();
```

But this exaple doesn't tell me anything.  What language is this - is it javascript, or is it typescript.  How is it getting included in my html, do i have to install yarn or power or tsc, like, literally - i have no idea how to make this do anything.

Comment: xterm.js is written in Typescript, thus all doc snippets are Typescript as well.

Comment: Not so, the base tutorial only refers to xterm.js and uses vanilla js an html, then the addons have this nonsense.